# Multi-value cells not filtering properly

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) and have some rows with cells containing multiple values. The counts appear correctly in the search pane, but when clicked, do not show the rows containing the multiple values. See row #1 which has two "Offices". Any suggestions?

```js
var dataSet = [
    ['Tiger Nixon', 'System Architect', 'Edinburgh', '5421', '2011/04/25', '$320,800'],
    ['Garrett Winters', 'Accountant', 'Tokyo', '8422', '2011/07/25', '$170,750'],
    ['Ashton Cox', 'Junior Technical Author', 'San Francisco', '1562', '2009/01/12', '$86,000'],
    ['Cedric Kelly', 'Senior Javascript Developer', 'Edinburgh', '6224', '2012/03/29', '$433,060'],
    ['Airi Satou', 'Accountant', ['Tokyo', 'Edinburgh'], '5407', '2008/11/28', '$162,700'],
    ['Brielle Williamson', 'Integration Specialist', 'New York', '4804', '2012/12/02', '$372,000'],
    ['Herrod Chandler', 'Sales Assistant', 'San Francisco', '9608', '2012/08/06', '$137,500'],
    ['Rhona Davidson', 'Integration Specialist', 'Tokyo', '6200', '2010/10/14', '$327,900'],
    ['Colleen Hurst', 'Javascript Developer', 'San Francisco', '2360', '2009/09/15', '$205,500'],
    ['Sonya Frost', 'Software Engineer', 'Edinburgh', '1667', '2008/12/13', '$103,600']
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: 'Name' },
            { title: 'Position' },
            { title: 'Office' },
            { title: 'Extn.' },
            { title: 'Start date' },
            { title: 'Salary' },
        ],
        dom: 'Pfrtip'
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.6/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.2.4/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.3.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.7/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/2.0.2/css/searchPanes.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.4.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.6/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.2.4/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.3.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.7/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/2.0.2/js/dataTables.searchPanes.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.4.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work via `render`:

```js
var dataSet = [
    ['Tiger Nixon', 'System Architect', 'Edinburgh', '5421', '2011/04/25', '$320,800'],
    ['Garrett Winters', 'Accountant', 'Tokyo', '8422', '2011/07/25', '$170,750'],
    ['Ashton Cox', 'Junior Technical Author', 'San Francisco', '1562', '2009/01/12', '$86,000'],
    ['Cedric Kelly', 'Senior Javascript Developer', 'Edinburgh', '6224', '2012/03/29', '$433,060'],
    ['Airi Satou', 'Accountant', ['Tokyo', 'Edinburgh'], '5407', '2008/11/28', '$162,700'],
    ['Brielle Williamson', 'Integration Specialist', 'New York', '4804', '2012/12/02', '$372,000'],
    ['Herrod Chandler', 'Sales Assistant', 'San Francisco', '9608', '2012/08/06', '$137,500'],
    ['Rhona Davidson', 'Integration Specialist', 'Tokyo', '6200', '2010/10/14', '$327,900'],
    ['Colleen Hurst', 'Javascript Developer', 'San Francisco', '2360', '2009/09/15', '$205,500'],
    ['Sonya Frost', 'Software Engineer', 'Edinburgh', '1667', '2008/12/13', '$103,600']
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [{
                title: 'Name'
            },
            {
                title: 'Position'
            },
            {
                title: 'Office',
                render: function(data, type, row) {
                    if (type === 'sp') {
                        if (data != null && data.includes(",")) {
                            return data.split(",");
                        } else {
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                    return data;
                },
                searchPanes: {
                    orthogonal: 'sp'
                }
            },
            {
                title: 'Extn.'
            },
            {
                title: 'Start date'
            },
            {
                title: 'Salary'
            },
        ],
        dom: 'Pfrtip'
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.6/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.2.4/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.3.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.7/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/2.0.2/css/searchPanes.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.4.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.6/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.2.4/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.3.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.7/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/2.0.2/js/dataTables.searchPanes.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.4.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```